# Are questions like "Which country watches the most anime allowed"

Tags: support, acceptable-questions, asking-questions

I was wondering how people feel about these questions. I'm not sure whether these would count as a questions on Anime & Manga, but what would be you advice on questions like these and would they be closed. It would be likely to be closed, but really i'm looking for an opinion.

Helpful answers will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your feeling of wanting them closed.

I personally find it a very risky question as it is still anime production wise related, which should make it a question that is allowed on the site. The information necessary to answer this isn't really laying around either, it would take a huge effort to compare the viewer statistics that are released to the public and make a worthy answer out of it, even though without citation it can be answered in a 1 liner.

The fact that the answer to this specific question is really hard to obtain, and ever fluctuating (viewer numbers rise and drop on regular occasions)

So my view, as long as they don't stray to far from the [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production), so for example "What is the most watched anime in Philippines" would be close to impossible to answer, and if it is answerable the answer would be ever fluctuating.

My view on this individual question, the information is hard to obtain, takes a huge effort to make a non 1 liner good answer for it. And I personally think closing it as to broad. Also the information from this ( after doing some research ) fluctuates allot making it very hard to maintain a solid answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm more-or-less fine with this sort of question.

First off, it's on topic in my opinion. A question might be off-topic if it were highly specific to the reception of anime in a particular culture (other than Japanese culture IMO). However, this question has a global perspective. It's about how anime is recieved, which is something that ought to be on topic here.

I also don't think it's opinion-based. A good answer to this question calls for some statistics, not opinions. If anything, it's less opinion-based than all the [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) questions that mostly never get objective answers or go beyond duplicating content that's already listed elsewhere on Wikipedia or TVTropes.

I don't think it's too broad either. There aren't very many possible answers, and answers themselves wouldn't need to be very long. Listing the 5-10 top countries by some statistic, and a couple paragraphs of explanation, would probably be sufficient. If someone already had such data available, it would not be a very challenging question to answer.

What this question may be is *too hard*. The data don't seem to have been collected, and doing it would require some sort of international polling that's pretty difficult. However, that is *not* a reason to close the question. If it were, virtually every nontrivial question on niche series would also be too hard. When a question is too hard, the proper course of action is just to not answer it. If you think it's too hard for *anyone* to answer, then downvoting (ideally with a comment) would be reasonable, but I'd be very surprised if no one in the world knew which countries anime is popular in. There are definitely ways one could study this, e.g. looking at export data, traffic to major anime sites, etc. It would not surprise me if there were academic papers which already perform this analysis. If it hasn't been performed, then it's pretty intensive to do well, which means that it probably won't get answered, but all that closing the question would do is change "hard" to "impossible".